# How to simplifying the following integral that involves Bessel functions and Exponential integral function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I have obtained the following as a solution of heat conduction equation of a semi-infinite model in cylindrical coordinates which is initially subject to non-homogenous initial condition and isolated boundary conditions. The solution describes the temperature at the inner boundary of the semi-infinite model. I expect this solution to be simplified to simple functions involving exponential function. I have tried to evaluate the integration using Mathematica but it outputs the solution without simplification. This form of integral usually appears when the inner radius of the semi-infinite is finite as in my case. However, since the inner radius of the semi-infinite model in my problem is very small, the solution usually simplifies to exponential function/integral. I wonder if I can use some methods in Mathematica to do this.

```
rTD Integrate[ 
  Exp[-2 (t + tinj)/θ λ^2] (BesselY[0, λ] - 
     BesselJ[0, λ]/π ExpIntegralEi[
       t/θ λ^2]) (BesselJ[0, λ] BesselY[1, 
       rTD λ] - 
     BesselJ[1, rTD λ] BesselY[0, λ])/( 
   BesselJ[0, λ]^2 + BesselY[0, λ]^2), {λ, 0, 
   Infinity}]
```

I think also the following expression may be simplified for large values of rTD.

```
(BesselJ[0, λ] BesselY[1, rTD λ] - 
  BesselJ[1, rTD λ] BesselY[0, λ])
```

In this solution all constants are real and positive. Any ideas to simplify this integral will be appreciated. I am looking for approximate solution of this integral mainly when both rTD is large.

I have tried to use AsymptoticIntegrate and I get the following message error.

```
 AsymptoticIntegrate[ 
 Exp[- (t + tinj)/θ λ^2] (BesselY[0, λ] - 
    BesselJ[0, λ]/π ExpIntegralEi[
      t/θ λ^2]) (BesselJ[0, λ] BesselY[1, 
      rTD λ] - 
    BesselJ[1, rTD λ] BesselY[0, λ])/( 
  BesselJ[0, λ]^2 + BesselY[0, λ]^2), {λ, 0, 
  Infinity}, rTD -> Infinity]
```

```
AsymptoticIntegrate::pspec: Parameter specification rTD->∞ is not a list with three elements.
```

In the following, I have tried to use Series function. It simplifies the integrate, however Complex numbers appear. How can I eliminate the complex numbers in the following result.

```
FullSimplify[
 Series[Exp[-(t + tinj)/θ λ^2] (BesselY[0, λ] -
      BesselJ[0, λ]/π ExpIntegralEi[
       t/θ λ^2]) (BesselJ[0, λ] BesselY[1, 
        rTD λ] - 
      BesselJ[1, rTD λ] BesselY[0, λ])/(BesselJ[
        0, λ]^2 + BesselY[0, λ]^2), {rTD , Infinity, 
   1}]]
```

```
E^SeriesData[rTD, 
DirectedInfinity[1], {
   Complex[0, 1] λ, 
    Complex[0, -1] Pi - (t + tinj) θ^(-1) λ^2}, -1, 2, 
   1] (
SeriesData[rTD, 
DirectedInfinity[1], {Complex[
Rational[1, 2], 
Rational[-1, 2]] Pi^Rational[-3, 2] λ^Rational[-1, 2] BesselJ[
      0, λ] (
       BesselJ[0, λ]^2 + BesselY[0, λ]^2)^(-1) (
      Pi BesselY[0, λ] - BesselJ[0, λ] ExpIntegralEi[
       t θ^(-1) λ^2])}, 1, 3, 2]) + E^SeriesData[rTD, 
DirectedInfinity[1], {
   Complex[0, -1] λ, 
    Complex[0, -1] Pi - (t + tinj) θ^(-1) λ^2}, -1, 2, 
   1] (
SeriesData[rTD, 
DirectedInfinity[1], {Complex[
Rational[1, 2], 
Rational[1, 2]] Pi^Rational[-3, 2] λ^Rational[-1, 2] BesselJ[
      0, λ] (
       BesselJ[0, λ]^2 + BesselY[0, λ]^2)^(-1) (
      Pi BesselY[0, λ] - BesselJ[0, λ] ExpIntegralEi[
       t θ^(-1) λ^2])}, 1, 3, 2]) + Cos[
SeriesData[rTD, 
DirectedInfinity[1], {λ, Rational[1, 4] Pi}, -1, 2, 1]] (
SeriesData[rTD, 
DirectedInfinity[1], {
    2^Rational[1, 2] E^(-(t + tinj) θ^(-1) λ^2)
        Pi^Rational[-3, 2] λ^Rational[-1, 2] BesselY[
      0, λ] (
       BesselJ[0, λ]^2 + BesselY[0, λ]^2)^(-1) (
      Pi BesselY[0, λ] - BesselJ[0, λ] ExpIntegralEi[
       t θ^(-1) λ^2])}, 1, 3, 2]) + (
SeriesData[rTD, 
DirectedInfinity[1], {
    Rational[3, 4]
       2^Rational[-1, 2] E^(-(t + tinj) θ^(-1) λ^2)
        Pi^Rational[-3, 2] λ^Rational[-3, 2] BesselY[
      0, λ] (
       BesselJ[0, λ]^2 + BesselY[
         0, λ]^2)^(-1) (-Pi BesselY[0, λ] + BesselJ[
        0, λ] ExpIntegralEi[t θ^(-1) λ^2])}, 3,
     4, 2]) Sin[
SeriesData[rTD, 
DirectedInfinity[1], {λ, Rational[1, 4] Pi}, -1, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Mathematica will only try to apply exact replacements when trying to simplify an expression. You on the other hand seem to be looking for reasonable approximations given the special case of your model. You will have to suggest those yourself.

Comment: I tried to find approximate solution when both t and rTD are relatively large. @MarcoB

Comment: If you are using version 11.3 or later (updated in 12.1), look at [`AsymptoticIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticIntegrate.html)

Comment: I have tried to use AsymptoticIntegrate, however I find the following error message. AsymptoticIntegrate::pspec: Parameter specification rTD->\[Infinity] is not a list with three elements. I am using Mathematica 12.0. When I checked the function, I find it takes range for rTD like {rTD, value 1, value 2} in my version. @Bob Hanlon

Comment: Edit your question to show the code that you used along with the error that you received.